# Visualize country with region in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a project in which I have to stimulate the interaction between civilians and politicians. So I work with politician profiles, civilians can ask questions to this politicians, ... These politicians belong to a certain region in Belgium.

I want to implement a map with the different regions. If you click on a region, I want to show the questions of the different politicians that belong to that region.

Is this possible in ASP.NET MVC 4? If yes, can you explain me how or share me a link to an article? If no, other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Google Maps would be a good option for your project. This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/629913/Google-Maps-in-MVC-with-Custom-InfoWindow) should help outline the basics of using the Google Maps API with MVC 4. Also refer to this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17774388/3397281) on SO. Good luck!